# How to output edited Jtable data?

Tags: java, xml, swing, pdf, jtable

I am writing a program in eclipse. I need to create a GUI for user to edit a XML file and output the edited data by new xml file and PDF.

I have saved the data in array and put it in jTable but failed to save the edited data by FileOutputStream(Jbutton"output"). I had try that using FileOutputStream(Jbutton"output") successfully output the data but after edited it not work.

It will show the error like:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.swing.JTable$CellEditorRemover
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTable.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at testing.Saving$3.actionPerformed(Saving.java:90)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How can I output the edited data?

GUI:

```
package testing;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Saving extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable table;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JButton btnOutput;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Saving frame = new Saving();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Saving() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
//      String[] array = {"text","apple","orange","tree"};
        table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {
                {"Name","text","apple","orange","tree"},
            },
            new String[] {
                "New column", "New column", "New column"
            }
        ));
        table.setBounds(46, 41, 324, 69);
        contentPane.add(table);

        JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");
        btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                model.setValueAt(textField.getText(),  table.getSelectedRow(),1);
                table.invalidate();
            }
        });
        btnSave.setBounds(46, 161, 87, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnSave);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(46, 130, 96, 21);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        btnOutput = new JButton("Output");
        btnOutput.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new
                    FileOutputStream("tableVM"));
                    oos.writeObject(table);
                    oos.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException a) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    a.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException a) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    a.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        });
        btnOutput.setBounds(143, 161, 87, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnOutput);
    }
}
```

output to pdf:

```
package testing;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
public class testing {
public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
try {
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new
FileInputStream("tableVM"));
JTable table = (JTable) ois.readObject();
ois.close();
TableModel tm = table.getModel();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("Selected.pdf"));
document.open();
document.addCreationDate();
document.add(new Paragraph("Brand: "));
for (int i = 0; i < tm.getRowCount(); i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < tm.getColumnCount(); j++) {
     document.add(new Phrase(tm.getValueAt(i, j) + "\t"));
}
System.out.println();
}
document.close();
writer.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

["Properties for java.io.NotSerializableException"]][1

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) The stack trace is missing the vital first line(s) that give information on the type of the exception. Make sure to include those.

Comment: I create a shorter example and provide the full error message, hope it is helpful.

Comment: What does your research into `NotSerializableException` suggest?

Comment: It guide me to "Properties for java.io.NotSerializableException" , the screen shot is appended at the bottom of this question.

Comment: *"It guide me to "Properties for java.io.NotSerializableException" ,"* Hmm.. it's a pity it did not guide you to the **JavaDocs** for [`NotSerializableException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/NotSerializableException.html)! As programmers, we will encounter a lot of exceptions in our careers, and the first thing you should try doing is understanding what the exception means, and the best place to start with that understanding is the description of the exception in the official documentation.